# Two Ways of Formatting DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a *DateTime* property and in my Model I have this:

```
[Display(Name = "Date:")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required!")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Day { get; set; }
```

This works perfectly fine, but I have a ViewModel that is getting populated with whatever value this property holds and on the ViewModel's View I need the date to also display the `tt` part of a DateTime Format.

So I have tried this in the `cshtml` of the ViewModel:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Day, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}")
```

but this still renders without the `tt`.  Is there a way that on some View's the display format can be `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm` and on others the display format can be `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt` for the same property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.DisplayFor(..` will always use the `DisplayFormat` specified on the model. So your code wont work.

In order to get the 'tt' part of the date you can try this. (since you are only displaying the datetime and not editing it)

```
<div>
<span> @item.Day.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt") </span>
</div>
```